# Node.js Google API error, Invalid Credentials...not sure what I'm doing with tokens and trying to make Google server side calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to pull emails from Google's Gmail API once they are on a specific page of my application. The users, once they are at this page already have signed in and are authenticated with my application and I have full access to read/write/edit emails.

I'm having trouble running the a gmail.users.threads.list() function after this step. Could anyone try to help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly?

I thought I could use the token I obtained once the user has signed in and authenticated with my application but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Below is the code:

```
const async = require('async');
const Order_info_item_scrape = require('../models/Order_info_item_scrape.js');
const Message = require('../models/Message.js');
var message_data = []
const passport = require('passport');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
  process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
  process.env.REDIRECT_URIS
);

var gmail = google.gmail({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: oauth2Client
});


google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });

exports.getOrder = (req, res) => {

  if (req.user.initial_scrape_state == 'need_initial') {
    console.log('here')

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      access_token: req.user.tokens[0].accessToken,
      refreshToken: req.user.tokens[0].accessToken
    });


    oauth2Client.getToken(oauth2Client.access_token, function (err, tokens) {
      // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
      if (!err) {
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      }
    });

    oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function(err, tokens) {
      // your access_token is now refreshed and stored in oauth2Client
      // store these new tokens in a safe place (e.g. database)
    });

      var message

      var retailers = ['contact@em.nordstrom.com']
      var key_words = '{subject:order subject:reciept subject:confirmation subject:purchase}'
      query = 'in: anywhere,' + retailers +','+ key_words
      //console.log(query)
      gmail.users.threads.list({
        auth: oauth2Client,
        userId: req.user.email,
        q: query
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {

          console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
          return;
        }

        var threads = response['threads']
        if (threads.length == 0) {

          console.log('No labels found.');

        } else {

          for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            var thread = threads[i];
            console.log(req.user.email)

            //getMessage(i ,auth, thread)

          }
        }
      });





  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to assign the user's access token as the [refresh token](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/), and then trying to feed that as the creds to your .list() call.

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      access_token: req.user.tokens[0].accessToken,
      refreshToken: req.user.tokens[0].accessToken
    });
```

Also, if you take a look at [Google's quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) you'll notice that it assigns the `oauth2Client.credentials` directly. I wonder if your `.credentials` property is ever getting actually assigned.